# Translation of "IOU"

Tags: português-europeu

I wish to know the Portuguese for "IOU". I.e. an informal note someone may write on a piece of paper to acknowledge that they owe someone something. It appears impossible to search for it in online dictionaries because IOU isn't a word and if I searched for "I owe you" I am concerned that the answer might not be the same thing.

I also want to be sure that it really means the same thing, so for example I don't want a technical term that only economists or bankers would use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An IOU is a word. It's on Wikipedia:

[IOU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IOU)

A palavra quer dizer e se traduz por (um) reconhecimento de dívida

Não há outra tradução.

- O reconhecimento de dívida designa a declaração unilateral mediante a qual alguém reconhece uma dívida a outrem.

[Lexionário](https://dre.pt/web/guest/lexionario/-/dj/159129086/view)

An IOU can be something official between companies, say, or just a paper I write and sign, saying I owe someone money. It is not a negotiable instruments. The negotiable debt instrument is called a promissory note, nota promissória.

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR — I'd suggest: "*declaração* (or *nota*) *de dívida*" for pt-BR.

---

The OP is explicitly about pt-PT and is already answered in Lambie's [post](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/a/8789/2764), but it seems to make more sense to address here too the translation to pt-BR than to have a separate question for it.

It's difficult to find a good translation, since the exact concept is not used in Brazilian Portuguese.

The most immediate translation could seem to be "*nota promissória*", but this is "promissory note", a more formal, negotiable instrument, as Lambie's answer explains. One could perhaps consider an IOU as an informal promissory note, what suggests the translation "*nota promissória informal*" — which is correct enough and understandable, but has the big disadvantage of never being used in practice (as Google's 6 hits attests).

Translation suggestions [include](https://www.teclasap.com.br/iou/) "*título de dívida*", "*vale*", "*recibo*, and "*adiantamento*", none of which really works: "*título de dívida*" is "debt security", "debenture" or other financial asset; " "*vale*" is rather "coupon" or "voucher", thus a IOU of sorts, but only in specific, usually commercial contexts; "*recibo* is "receipt" and thus too general; and "*adiantamento*" is actually unrelated, meaning things such as "retainer" or "advance".

So we're left with using a description for a translation, such as, for pt-PT, "*reconhecimento de dívida*" ("acknowledgment of debt") or, for pt-BR, "*declaração de dívida*" ("statement or declaration of debt"). Notice that "*reconhecimento de dívida*" doesn't work so well in pt-BR because in Brazil this expression [refers to](https://ambitojuridico.com.br/cadernos/direito-administrativo/reconhecimento-de-divida-em-contratos-publicos/) a specific government issued document.

Comment: Sorry but this isn't right. **A promissory note is an negotiable instrument; an IOU is not;** IOU are used between individuals or businesses; My answer covered most of what you say, and some of yours is not relevant. Just because reconhecimento de dívida is a term the gov't uses **does not mean** it can't be used in other contexts...

Comment: @Lambie, That's exactly what I **already wrote** in my answer: `"promissory note", a more formal, negotiable instrument, as Lambie's answer] explains.`.

Comment: @Lambie But I weakened my claim that "reconhecimento" can't be used, since possibly it might - but I keep it there because this meaning (governmental) seems to be so prevalent as to cause confusion if used with another meaning.

Comment: If think if I said to you: Vou te dar um reconhecimento escrito de dívida, everyone would get it. I think posting all the stuff is isn't just isn't useful. :)

Comment: @Lambie My bet is that a lack of upvotes is likely to confirm your opinion, but I still believe in this contribution. :)

Comment: I agree with Lambie, it is not useful to say all the things that it isn't when OP is looking for what it IS. Also important point that you're missing in your answer about PT-BR is that *an IOU is not a cultural practice for us*. There is no exact translation because we don't do it. The closest thing to an IOU we have is a "confissão de dívida" but that's already FAR more detailed and formal than the usual IOU

Comment: Hi @JulianaKarasawaSouza, I know we don't use it and that's actually exactly what I meant with `the exact concept is not used in Brazilian Portuguese`. As for going about what IOUs aren't, the reason I do it is because those are suggestions that are found online, so it's helpful to point out why they aren't good suggestions after all.